# How can lambda be used to keep DynamoDB and Cloud Search in sync

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, amazon-cloudsearch

Assuming we're using AWS Triggers on DynamoDB Table, and that trigger is to run a lambda function, whose job is to update entry into CloudSearch (to keep DynamoDB and CS in sync).

I'm not so clear on how Lambda would always keep the data in sync with the data in dynamoDB. Consider the following flow:

1. Application updates a DynamoDB table's Record A (say to A1)
2. Very closely after that Application updates same table's same record A (to A2)
3. Trigger for 1 causes Lambda of 1 to start execute
4. Trigger for 2 causes Lambda of 2 to start execute
5. Step 4 completes first, so CloudSearch sees A2
6. Now Step 3 completes, so CloudSearch sees A1

Lambda triggers are not guaranteed to start ONLY after previous invocation is complete (Correct if wrong, and provide me link)

As we can see, the thing goes out of sync.

The closest I can think which will work is to use AWS Kinesis Streams, but those too with a single Shard (1MB ps limit ingestion). If that restriction works, then your consumer application can be written such that the record is first processed sequentially, i.e., only after previous record is put into CS, then the next record should be processed. Assuming the aforementioned statement is true, how to ensure the sync happens correctly, if there is so much of data ingestion into DynamoDB that more than one shards are needed n Kinesis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AWS Lambda F&Q Link](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/)

> **Q: How does AWS Lambda process data from Amazon Kinesis streams and Amazon DynamoDB Streams?**
>
> The Amazon Kinesis and DynamoDB Streams records sent to your AWS Lambda function are strictly serialized, per shard. This means that if you put two records in the same shard, Lambda guarantees that your Lambda function will be successfully invoked with the first record before it is invoked with the second record. If the invocation for one record times out, is throttled, or encounters any other error, Lambda will retry until it succeeds (or the record reaches its 24-hour expiration) before moving on to the next record. The ordering of records across different shards is not guaranteed, and processing of each shard happens in parallel.

So that means Lambda would pick the Records in one shard one by one, in order they appear in the Shard, and not execute a new record until previous record is processed!

However, the other problem that remains is what if the entries of the same record are present across different shards? Thankfully, AWS DynamoDB Streams ensure that primary key only resides in a particular Shard always. (Essentially, I think, the Primary Key is what is used to find the hash to point to a shard) [AWS Slide Link](https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/realtime-data-processing-with-amazon-dynamodb-streams-and-aws-lambda-7302015/22). See [more from AWS Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-update-triggers-streams-lambda-cross-region-replication-app/) below:

> The relative ordering of a sequence of changes made to a single primary key will be preserved within a shard. Further, a given key will be present in at most one of a set of sibling shards that are active at a given point in time. As a result, your code can simply process the stream records within a shard in order to accurately track changes to an item.

Comment: have you got any limitations using dynamoDB streams to update cloudsearch? I read the docs and it says that you can only request 1 batch / 10 seconds. What if the updates in dynamodb occurs lower than 10 seconds?

Comment: That doesnt matter. The 10 second limit just says you cannot make several requests in that time limit. But you'll always get the correct data if APIs are made within those limits. So even if your updates happen at milliseconds, you'd always want to check the changes from T1 to T2. So you'll need to write the consumer code such that it sleeps for say 12 sec (anything more than 10 is okay), and then makes API hit to get data from last invoked End Time to Current Time. Even if Current Time - Last Invoked End Time is more than 10 seconds, the API would correctly send the results.

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve that using DynamoDB Streams:

[DynamoDB Streams](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html)

"A DynamoDB stream is an ordered flow of information about changes to items in an Amazon DynamoDB table."

DynamoDB Streams guarantees the following:

- Each stream record appears exactly once in the stream.
- For each item that is modified in a DynamoDB table, the stream records appear in the same sequence as the actual modifications to the item.

Another cool thing about DynamoDB Streams, if your Lambda fails to handle the stream (any error when indexing in Cloud Search for example) the event will keep retrying and the other record streams will wait until your context succeed.

We use Streams to keep our Elastic Search indexes in sync with our DynamoDB tables.

Comment: Yes, Dynamo Stream does what we want, but what if number of shards goes beyond 1 (due to high inflow of data updates)? In that case, your records would be split to two different shards. So the sequential ordering assumption would go for a toss

Comment: I guess you can handle this situation using [DynamoDB Streams Kinesis Adapter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.KCLAdapter.html)

I think the key point here, to validate what the documentation says, is testing. Write your Lambda function, force an error, sees if another event will be triggered or will wait until your previous record be successfully processed. Also, try to reproduce a high amount of data being inserted or updated in your table, whether choosing dynamodb streams or not, you'll have to test your scenario with any solution that you choose.

Comment: Tom, the moment we get multiple shards into picture, each shard would have record ordered (within the records of that shard), but not across shards. So my question really is, with Kinesis (or DynamoDB streams or even Kafka for that matter), how would we ensure that we get global ordered records, even if multiple shards are there?

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer, I'll dive into the details, we could have the same situation here!

Comment: Tom, as long as you expect all records of a single Primary Key (Partition + Range) to be processed in correct-order, it would not matter. However, if your processing requires a global ordering, then there's nothing that could help. If you are using the Dynamo Streams + Lambda to just sync the Elastic Search, then you are good (as my answer describes). However, if you are also doing anything other than that, which requires correct global ordering, and your ingestion rate exceeds 1MBps, then you're out of luck.